# Connect Google Apps Email from Outlook via Linux ipTables

Tags: linux, iptables, squid

I have set up my google apps email on my outlook and I want it to connect to the google server  and fetch my mails using SSL POP3

Ports 995, 465 both TCP and UDP are open. But it still not working.  The server has 2 NIC, one for LAN and the other for External.

Please provide assistance on solving this issue.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: you might want to provide your firewall script and clarify where those ports are open.

just generally, more info pls

Answer (score 0):

From the machine running iptables, can you do:-

`openssl s_client -connect <google POP3 IP>:995`

If you can make a connection, then the connection isn't on the external side. If you can't, then there's your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try using port 587 instead of 465.